# MS flow with Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

Currently I have a MS flow where I send email with a attachment file to  support groups.After sending email the attachment gets saved on Sharepoint list.

I am facing an problem when I have to capture the response back.They send  response back via comments and attach image files.

I want the list column should only attach image file and until the user attach the file the  status column cannot be change to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Are the comments and image files sent by Email? There are triggers to start the Flow when new email arrives and get the Email body, attachment. Then add the attachment to your list item. I tested with a simple sample and it works fine. You may need a bit more work to get the correct list item id through the Email.

[image]

For the status column, I will suggest you to add a new Flow to be triggered when the item is modified. It checks the attach file column and will update the status column according to whether the image file is attached.

Comment: The users will attach the file manually. So we need to handle this in Sharepoint.

Comment: @user6167232 Then we need to change the trigger and get attachment action to those in SharePoint, the process is quite similar